# Order 2 cast in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If I've got an `v` I can call

cast :: a -> Maybe b

So I can take an `a` and get back a `b` if the cast is successful (I've elided the details of `Typeable` constraints).

However, I've got a nastier case. I have a type `Value x y`. I only actually care about the first type parameter, not the second. So really I want to be able to cast `v` to `Value x y2` and be free in the second parameter (the rest of my code is OK with this).

How can I achieve this? To be clear, at this point I have no idea if `v` is a `Value` of any variety, let alone a `Value x`.

Comment: That would very much depend on the definition of `Value`.

Comment: You can't use `cast` to change types arbitrarily, it will fail. If `v :: Value Int Char`, then `cast v :: Maybe (Value Int Bool)` will return `Nothing`. I think you need a real conversion function, which exploits `Value`'s constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cast` alone can't do this because it needs to know the types of all variables, but its implementation is quite simple so you can write your own. `cast` checks `a` and `b` are the same type and `unsafeCoerce`s it if they match.

You can do something using `typeRepCon`. This deconstructs a `TypeRep` into the type constructer and a list of types that make it's parameters. First match the type constructors to make sure it's a `Value`, then check if `y` is the same. If everything matches you can `unsafeCoerce`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}
import Unsafe.Coerce
import Data.Typeable

data Value x y = Value x y
  deriving Typeable

data Box where
  Box :: Typeable a => a -> Box

value :: Value Int Char
value = Value 3 'a'

box :: Box
box = Box value

box2 :: Box
box2 = Box 'Z'

getValueY :: forall a y. (Typeable a, Typeable y) => a -> Maybe (forall x. Value x y)
getValueY a
  | con == typeRepTyCon (typeOf value) && y == typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy y) 
      = Just $ unsafeCoerce a
  | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    (con, ~[_x, y]) = splitTyConApp (typeOf a)

valueChar :: Value x Char -> Char
valueChar (Value _ c) = c

boxChar :: Box -> Maybe Char
boxChar (Box b) =
  case getValueY b of
    Just v  -> Just (valueChar v)
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

which gives

```
>>> getY box
Just 'a'
>>> getY box2
Nothing
```

The impredicative type (`forall x. Value x y`) is here to make sure you can't choose what x is, otherwise you could make it whatever you want as long as the `y` matches. Another (possibly nicer) solution is make another wrapper like

```
data YValue y where
  YValue :: Value x y -> YValue y
  deriving Typeable
```

A lot of the trouble comes from not even knowing it's a `Value`, otherwise you could use `gcast`.

---

**Edit**: you can avoid `ImpredicativeTypes` completely by giving it a `forall x. Value x y -> b` function:

```
withValueY :: forall a y b. (Typeable a, Typeable y)
           => (forall x. Value x y -> b) -> a -> Maybe b
withValueY f a
  | con == typeRepTyCon (typeOf value) && y == typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy y)
      = Just $ f (unsafeCoerce a)
  | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    (con, ~[_x, y]) = splitTyConApp (typeOf a)

boxChar :: Box -> Maybe Char
boxChar (Box b) = withValueY valueChar b
```

Comment: This seems like something that would be solved by the [proposed Typeable redesign](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Typeable). In particular if the current API had had something like `withTypeable`, then `unsafeCoerce` could be avoided because you could construct existentially the desired type to `cast` into. Or presumably the decomposition functions could be used more directly.

Comment: I ended up using your second approach and doing `forall x y` and then using normal casts once I'd asserted in was at least a `Value`.